Virtual Cable on Linux - How to import audio from a source ( app ) , for example, to a microhpne
it seems there is no app able to do such a thing on Linux.
I checked for Vb-Audio Cable, Vac and VOicemeter, which seem to be the most popular ones. I am a new user on linux, and would like to know if there is an easy way of doing this ?
--
If this is not the place for this kind of question, feel free to delete it.

You don't have to set up anything special – the sound system of modern Linux distros already have all the functionality built-in. (Specifically, every not-esoteric Linux distro uses pipewire these days, and that can route streams however you like.)
So, if you just need to connect a specific microphone to a specific applications (say, your webcam microphone to your browser), then pavucontrol already does what you need. It's available on all Linux distros I'm aware of.

it seems there is no app able to do such a thing on Linux.

There's numerous ways to achieve routing audio between applications; in the end, it's just a question of giving you a good interface to the functionality brought by your system.
So, you can just use the standard pavucontrol mixer together with loopback "monitor" devices that you set up yourself, or you use a graphical program like qpwgraph; on debian, Ubuntu, Fedora and OpenSUSE it's in a package of that exact name. It looks like this:
Source: project repo
And unlike virtual cable software for Windows, it's not artificially limited in the number of connections unless you buy a full version.

Very Good Answer. Is it possible to create a virtual microphone trough the terminal.

Probably yes! But I don't know what specifically you mean with that – sounds to me like you really just want to connect an application to another one, as show above. But not sure. Please ask new questions as new question posts, not in the comments :) And be much more detailed than "virtual microphone". Describe precisely what you want to do, and how things should behave – it's sadly really not clear to me.

Alr, thanks for the kind answers! I know my question was bad!

your question isn't bad, it's just a bit unclear to someone who's not sitting next to you :) As said, please do ask it as a new post!
